# How to increase weight of wordcloud for weight value less than 5 in highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a wordcloud in highcharts,Here I need to change the weight dynamically whose value is less than 5 to visible each word properly.Here my max weight is 100 and other weights are like 5,2,1 so less weight word is not visible properly.
Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/wordcloud.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### script

```
 var data = [{
        name: 'Lorem',
        weight: 100
    }, {
        name: 'Ipsum',
        weight: 2
    }, {
        name: 'Dolor',
        weight: 1
    }];

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        series: [{
            type: 'wordcloud',
            data: data,
            name: 'Occurrences'
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your data and increase `weight` value for some points:

```
 data.forEach(function(el) {
     if (el.weight < 5) {
         el.weight *= 10;
     }
 });
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mun80gbo/